# Rails and blade: get rid of wrapper div only is some views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, laravel-blade

My master layout where `yield` is called looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</div>
```

This obviously acts as a wrapper for the content in my page and I was fine with it for the whole development process.

However, now I am trying to edit some views so they have a background image occupying the whole width of the screen, so this wrapper is now inconvenient.

I though of I way of doing this. Since I will use it only for the log-in and sign-in pages, I figured I could check in the master view what controller method is being executed, and depending on it the wrapper divs would be rendered or not.

So it looks something like this:

```
<% if current_page? controller: :registrations, action: :new %>
    <%= yield %>
<% else %>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I tested it on the sign up page and it worked!

However, when browsing to a different page, say, sign in, this error appears:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
```

And the outlined line with the error is `<% if current_page? controller: :registrations, action: :new %>`.

This doesn't make sense to me. What's wrong? How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

**edit** routes:

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                      devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                      devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                     devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                     devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                 devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                     devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                     devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                       registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                              registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                      registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                         registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                              registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                              registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                              registrations#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a web app setup similar to what you describe. The login page has a full background image. You'll need to tweak it for your purposes, but this is the idea.

helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
  # The home page uses a different container than all other pages
  def context_background
    if current_page?(login_url) 
       @container = "login-container"
    else
       @container = "container"
    end
  end
```

views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
   <div class="<%= context_background %>">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
```

Setup your CSS for your background image div of course. Let me know if you need assist with this part.

Comment: wait the worked for a moment but... I have a problem with devise. `current_page?(new_user_registration_path)` and `current_page?(new_user_session_path)` would match as expected. But if the sign up has errors it's redirected to the view but the url changes, so the css changes again. With `rake routes` I could see `user_registration_path` matches the url, however when passed as an argument to `current_page?` it returns false. Any help?

Comment: Which background do you want displayed when there is a signup error?

Comment: And...would you please post the output of your $rake routes?

Comment: I am updating my original post

Comment: Okay. I have an idea for a test. It isn't pretty but it might give us a hint as to what the problem is. Try this test, instead of using the path, use the explicit routing:  current_page?(controller: 'user_registration', action: 'post')

Comment: I think the action argument refers to the name of the action, not the method of the request. I changed my code so instead of using `current_page?` I am using `controller_name` and `action_name` and it works.

Comment: You're right of course about the controller action. I was fixating on POST. Good catch. Glad it's working and you've got the behaviors you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
<%else%>
  <%= yield %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: um no, that's not what I am trying to do by any means. I want to differentiate between sign in and sign out and the rest.